# Tooltips of data points in DateListPlot render dates as real numbers

Tags: tooltip, version-11

Last year (in V10.x) I created a `DateListPlot` of commodity price data. I used `Tooltip` to display the date and the data value from a date list. I upgraded to V11 and everything was fine. The tooltips would render properly like this: `{Fri 17 Feb 2017, 1.58}`

But after I upgraded to 11.1 the tooltips now render in scientific notation, like this (same date): {3.69628 x 10<sup>9</sup>, 1.58}

Here's the DateListPlot:

```
pListCurrYr = {{{2017, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.67}
, {{2017, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.66}, ...}; (* 3 mos. of data *)

DateListPlot[
 Tooltip[pListCurrYr]
 , PlotTheme -> "Classic"
 , AspectRatio -> 0.8
 , PlotLabel -> Style[
   Framed[
    "CME Block Cheese Prices from "
     <> DateString[
      pListCurrYr[[1, 1]], {"MonthName", " ", "DayShort"}] <> " to "
     <> DateString[
      pListCurrYr[[Length[pListCurrYr], 1]], {"MonthName", " ", 
       "DayShort", ", ", "Year"}]
    ]
   , "Subsection"
   ]
 , Filling -> Bottom
 , PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledDiamond], 18}
 , PlotRange -> {Full, {1.00, 2.00}}
 ]
```

I've tried to use `DateString` objects instead of `Date` objects in `pListCurrYr`, but `Tooltip` still interprets them in scientific notation.

Could you please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
DateListPlot[
 Tooltip[#, {DateString[#[[1]],
      {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "YearShort"}], #[[2]]}] & /@
  pListCurrYr,
 PlotTheme -> "Classic",
 AspectRatio -> 0.8,
 PlotLabel ->
  Style[Framed[
    "CME Block Cheese Prices from " <>
     DateString[pListCurrYr[[1, 1]],
      {"MonthName", " ", "DayShort"}] <> " to " <>
     DateString[pListCurrYr[[Length[pListCurrYr], 1]],
      {"MonthName", " ", "DayShort", ", ", "Year"}]], "Subsection"],
 Filling -> Bottom,
 PlotMarkers -> {◆, 18},
 PlotRange -> {Full, {1.00, 2.00}}]
```

Comment: I see! Alter the format of the date within the Tooltip itself instead of in the List. I appreciate the insight you've given me.